# ASP.NET and System.Web.Optimization not bundling css / js files

Tags: asp.net, bundle

I'm trying to use the bundling features of System.Web.Optimization to minify my css and java script.

I have installed the pre release via NuGet

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Optimization -Pre
```

and added the following references to my web.config files

/Views/Web.config

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    .....
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

/Web.config

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    .....
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

I am adding bundles like so

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Styles").IncludeDirectory("~/Styles", "*.css"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/App").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/App", "*.js"));
```

and rendering to my page like this

```
@Styles.Render("~/Styles")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/App")
```

Which works great until I turn off debug

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

The link and script tag added to my page are

```
<link href="/Styles?v=NMwU-eYeuzJZeywD3xbes6ngUXXJURhda30SEe9mb7Y1" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Scripts/App?v=NIL6McOTiWu9OPTVvgMfbmjFtYQhKZDQpRIbKK2kzSk1"></script>
```

Looking at Chromes network tab I get a 302 redirecting to

```
/Styles
/Scripts/App
```

Followed by a 404 :(

I can't seem to get this to work.... has anyone seen a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe have a conflict with your routing code?

[Rick Anderson has a blog post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) about the bundling / minification features, including a note that you must be careful to avoid routing conflicts. You haven't posted your routing section, but it's something to take a look at.